# changing ActionProvider to appcompat-v7

Tags: java, android

In order to extend AppCompatActivity in a MainActivity.java file,  the following was migrated from:

```
package me.site.site;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://third.second.tld/");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new com.androidwebviewapp.karthik.MyAppWebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                //hide loading image
                findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //show webview
                findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }});


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menu.findItem(R.id.share).getActionProvider();


        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

}
```

To

```
package me.site.site;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://third.second.tld/");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new me.site.site.MyAppWebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                //hide loading image
                findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //show webview
                findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }});


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);



        MenuItem item=menu.findItem(R.id.share);
        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(item);
```

** mShareActionProvider.setOnShareTargetSelectedListener(this); **

```
        return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));

    }



}
```

complains with an error referring to the code highlighted above

```
Error:(67, 33) error: method setOnShareTargetSelectedListener in class 

ShareActionProvider cannot be applied to given types;
required: OnShareTargetSelectedListener
found: MainActivity
reason: actual argument MainActivity cannot be converted to OnShareTargetSelectedListener by method invocation conversion
```

Comment: I've found this question in a review. The line `** mShareActionProvider.setOnShareTargetSelectedListener(this); **` seems wrong, but I am not sure how to fix it. Were you trying to make it bold? It doesn't work inside code blocks. Could you please check? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I was attempting to make it bold.  As stated in the question Android Studio `complains with an error referring to the code highlighted above`